# jQuery animate does not work while everything else does

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, try-catch

Could anyone could give me a clue on what I can do to debug jQuery in general and/or this issue in particular?

**Problem :**

**jQuery** method `animate()` behaves strangely.
The method is added to the `onclick` method of a `HTML element`, **javascript** generated.

This :

```
try{

    $(element).animate({
        width : '300px'
    });

}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Returns no error but the animate effect does not work.
However, this works :

```
try{

    $(element).animate({
        width : '300px'
    });
    $(element).css('background','pink');

}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

**Context :**

```
var onclick = function(){

    var element = this;

    $(element).css('background','pink');

    try{

    $(element).animate({
        width : '300px'
    });

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

var elem = document.create('div');
element.addEventListener('click',onclick,false);
```

*In fact, things are a bit much complicated, but I simplify to clarify the issue.*

I know that **jQuery** is working, since `$(element).css('background','pink')` is correctly executed.

Everything is correctly injected into head context :

[image]

As you can noticed, I have added `jQuery-UI` **just in case...**

I should mention that, some days ago when I noticed the problem the first time, I was not injecting things like this. I was instead `eval` content of `jquery-1.11.2.min.class.js` in my template (which is not the right way to do, I agree, but that was a draft) and I did not used **jQuery-UI**. And at this time, `try/catch` caught this error :

```
jquery Uncaught TypeError: (ec[b] || []).concat is not a function
```

And I was also and already able to use `$(element).css('background','pink');`

I should also mention that I use most often pure **Javascript** and very rarely **jQuery** in my code, but every `$` functions I needed since now has been working correctly.

**What I've tried :**

I find some similar issues on *SO*, but no solutions to fit my problem. By example, adding `$(document).ready` does not help me.

```
var onclick = function(){

    var element = this;

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(element).css('background','pink');

    try{

    $(element).animate({
        width : '300px'
    });

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}); 
}
```

I've not find much in *Google* about that, seems it is not a commons problem. However, I've learn a bit much about **jQuery**, namely that `concat` is use to `join two arrays`.

But, I am stucked and the difficulties I encounter stays, even if I have `no more error catched`.

Comment: a JSFiddle link is appreciated.

Comment: You have added `jquery-ui`, I agree, but twice??

Comment: oh yeah Guruprasad, I just parse and inject folder, there is a bit mess in it, I'm going to clean that but its should not impact here

Comment: Jquery library js also included twice one is minified and other is not

Comment: what is `jquery-1.11.2.min.class.js` for?

Comment: also seems that `element` is not that one what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe DIVs have `min-width` propertie set in CSS or a `width` with `!important` statement, who knows?... Anyway, in your posted code, you don't add the DIV anywhere in the DOM. So provide minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Comment: @Vinod : I'm trying to setup that, but Im not very good with jsfiddle

Comment: @jai : but  $(element).css('background','pink') works...

Comment: @wolff the element Im working with is <div id="992" style="position: fixed; float: left; width: 250px; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9999; display: block; background: rgb(255, 192, 203);"></div>

Comment: @GuillaumeFe Ok but inspect element to check for any CSS rules coming from somewhere else than inline style. And if you have issue setting a jsFiddle replicating issue, maybe you could provide online link where this issue can be checked

Comment: @Wolff unfortunately nothing is online for now :/ I can guarantee that no other style have been applied to the element. My design select some js object which are constituted by 4 objects (structure,design,methods,events). A loop build every element, beginning by childs. Parents elements could (or not) get all properties child have. I'm still on jsFiddle, but I fear it can not helps to reproduce the problem (as i have my own design pattern. If it s not possible to help me, because of lack of info, I would love to know a method that could help me to debug jquery.

Comment: "As you can noticed, I have added jQuery-UI just in case..." You shouldn't add frameworks just in case. In this case it might even hurt you since you load in before jquery and if I'm not mistaken jquery ui depends ono jquery and migt generate an error. Anyway, you have to provide more code for anyone to figure this out for you, either by jsfiddle or a gist on github...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally determinate what's going wrong, at least superficially.

My problem was coming from the fact that I added 2 prototypes to Object.
And jQuery, which might be internally kinda messy, does not like it at all.
So, it has been enough to remove every custom prototype added to Object to see jQuery working again.

Morality : do NOT had custom methods on Object if you plan to work with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! I was going mad "why something I've donw thousand times is not working properly"...reall... thanks :D